# Check if seaborn scatterplot function is sampling data

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot, sampling

I have plotted a seaborn scatter plot. My data consists of 5000 data points. By looking into the plot, I definitely am not seeing 5000 points. So I'm pretty sure some kind of sampling is performed by seaborn scatterplot function. I want to know how many data points each point in the plot represent? If it depends on the code, the code is as following:

```
g = sns.scatterplot(x=data['x'], y=data['y'],hue=data['P'], s=40,  edgecolor='k', alpha=0.8, legend="full")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: scatterplot does not sample the data. All data is plotted. Feel free to ask about your actual problem instead (see [mcve]).

Comment: Try adding a small random number to y (“jitter”). It will separate some of the points that overlap

Comment: are you sure that there are not 5000 points ? Some of them might be overlapping...

Comment: Actually I am not 100% sure. I want to make sure that no sampling is at play and all the points are plotted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing would really suggest to me that seaborn is sampling your data. However, you can check the data in your axes `g` to be sure. Query the children of the axes for a PathCollection (scatter plot) object:

```
g.get_children()
```

It's probably the first item in the list that is returned. From there you can use `get_offsets` to retrieve the data and check its shape.

```
g.get_children()[0].get_offsets().shape
```

Comment: This confirmed that no sampling is happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no sampling is performed. On the picture you have posted, you can see that most of the data points are just overlapping and that might be the reason why you can not see 5000 points. Try with less points and you will see that all of them get plotted.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check whether or not Seaborn's scatter removes points, here is a way to see 5000 different points. No points seem to be missing.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
y = np.linspace(1, 50, 50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = (X * Y) % 25
X = np.ravel(X)
Y = np.ravel(Y)
Z = np.ravel(Z)

sns.scatterplot(x=X, y=Y, s=15, hue=Z, palette=plt.cm.plasma, legend=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: 5000 points]

Comment: I don’t think this is conclusive, since it would be entirely reasonable for a scatter plot function to sample points that it thinks will overplot, but not from sparse regions of the plot. Such a function wouldn’t remove any points from your plot, but would conceivably remove them from OP’s plot.